# How to use TorchText to load FastText pre-trained word and subword embeddings?

Tags: torch, fasttext, torchtext

When using torch, TorchText provides ability to load word embedding from FastText pre-trained corpus. However, I am wondering would the same way can we get subword embedding in cases where out-of-vocabulary issues arise ?